# Faster way to process 120K List Items in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: powershell, splistitem, tasks

We have around 120K List Items in a SharePoint 2013 List. Now, we want to introduce an additional column and update the value based on the existing columns.

It is a dedicated - SharePoint farm and servers(4WFEs, 2Apps & DB server) has 4cores.

Now, we have two versions of Powershell script.

1. Iterate through all the Items sequencely and update - It takes 3hrs to complete.
2. Script will create 4tasks(one task per core) and process part of the Items - It takes 10hrs to complete.

Now, we want to reduce the execution time, what would be the best way to achieve? Why Tasking takes more time than sequential update?

Comment: did you consider writing some multi threaded server side code in a console application?

Comment: did you try [Web.ProcessBatchData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc404818(v=office.12).aspx) method?

Comment: We are looking for a system update so we donot want to change the modified details.